# After Android OpenGL ES 2.0 animation GLES20.glReadPixels reads the wrong value

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es, glreadpixels

I have this one square and when I click on it it stretches so it takes all the screen like shown in these pictures

Before stretching my color picker shows the values real nice

[image]

After the stretching when I click just a little below robots legs it gives me value (0,0,255) which is my background color, not the white color I clicked on (255,255,255).

[image]

I draw this animation very fast (100 ms) using `GLSurfaceView`'s   `setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY)`. The whole animation consists of only 6 frames.

The drawing itself happens from

```
...
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            do_stretching();
        }
}, 0, stretching_frame_delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
...

void do_stretching()
{
    //change coordinates of white squares vertices kind of "stretching" it
    surface_view.requestRenderer();
}
```

Animation is looking really good and fills all of `GLSurfaceView`'s area but color picker kind of acts like the last frame wouldn't be drawn and reads the background color which indeed was there before the animation completed. I noticed that if I draw this animation slower thus using more frames I can click a little closer to edges of this image and get the right results but still very close to edges there is this bug that `GLES20.glReadPixels` reads the background color even though its actually not visible after the animation completes. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Solved the issue by calling requestRenderer() 2 more times after the animation was actually drawn. But still I dont really know why this might be happening. Maybe something with double buffering?

Comment: actually  calling requestRenderer() 2 more times doesn't remove the issue it just makes it smaller % of chance that this incorrect reading will happen

Comment: I think I solved the issue by counting the times extra frames were rendered. If frame is not finished rendering and another requestRenderer() is called it wont have any effect so I counted that exactly 3 extra frames were rendered after my animation and that did the trick